# Why does Sublime block git, resulting in error: .git/index.lock exist?

Tags: git, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I am getting almost every time I try to do `git add .` through the linux terminal the following message:

```
fatal: Unable to create '/home/www/project/.git/index.lock': File exists.
If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

If I rm the file index.lock then everything works OK. This only occurs when Sublime Text is open. If I close the program I can commit through console without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the git module inside of Sublime solves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Deleting the index.lock must solve this issue.

Try issuing `del .git\index.lock`.

Comment: Is rm on linux not the same thing as del on windows?

Comment: Yes, they both are same.